# Web Part Missing/Error

Tags: field-type

I did a web app restore process by taking a backup of the Database(DB-A) of the concerned web app and then restoring it to another database(DB-B). I then created a new web app and attached the restored database to the newly created web app. but some of the links in the new web app respond as web part missing/Field type not installed properly etc.

The DB whose backup(DB-A) was taken and the DB to which it was restored(DB-B) to are on different domains with different ADs. Can this be the cause of the error due to some permission error? I have set full control to the user that access newly restored web app, but still the error persists.

Is there a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy the web parts that were deployed to the original App to the new environment. It seems you're missing an assembly or something. Backing up the content database will only get the content. But you need to deploy the dlls for these web parts in order for them to work.

Answer (score 0):

SO is there a workaround for the above process. Like i need to deploy a web app with all its web parts and field, so is there any method to take the backup and then restore it without any errors.
Because I am planning on migrating my entire sharepoint farm,so after i restore it is imperative that i dont hit any errors.